# Error al conectar react con la api de nodejs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, mongoose, nodemailer

estoy realizando un formulario en react en donde debe enviar los datos hacia un api que se conecta con nodemailer y envia un mensaje a mi correo personal con los datos del formulario pero cuando envio los datos por return fetch me envia un error como si no se estuviera enviando nada a través de los parametros

> contact.js:18 POST http://localhost:3977/api/v1/get-contact 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
 import {basePath, apiVersion} from './config';

export function getContactApi (inputs){
    const url = `${basePath}/${apiVersion}/get-contact`;
    const params = {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(inputs)
    }



    return fetch(url, params).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(result => {
        return result.message;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

    

}
```

lo raro es que cuando hago console.log de params.body me muestra correctamente los datos parseados a json que está recibiendo a través del formulario.

aclaro que estoy colocando los datos del formulario por un useState y los ingreso a través de un onChange

acá una parte del formulario

```
<Form.Item>
                    <Input
                    prefix={<UserOutlined style={{color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.25"}}/>}
                    placeholder="Nombres"
                    name="name"
                    value={inputs.name}
                    onChange={e => setInputs({...inputs, name: e.target.value})}
                    />
</Form.Item>
```

Y acá el useState

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        name: "",
        lastName: "", 
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        reason: ""
});
```

acá envio la data a el api a  través de onFinish del form

```
    const sendData = () => {
    console.log(inputs);
    getContactApi(inputs)
}
```

cuando hago console.log de inputs también me muestra correctamente los datos que se ingresan a inputs así que dudo que sea esa parte, tampoco creo que sea por parte del body: JSON.stringify(inputs) porque en el log se muestra correctamente, lo único que se me ocurre es que posiblemente en el controlador del backend algo esté obteniendo mal a través del api y no lo obtenga como un json o no lo obtenga en sí

acá el controlador

```
    const Contact = require('../models/contact');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

function putContact (req, res){

    const {name, lastName, phone, email, reason} = req.body;

    const contact = new Contact();
    
    contact.name = name;
    contact.lastName = lastName;
    contact.phone = phone;
    contact.email = email;
    contact.reason = reason;

    const datos = `
    <h3>Nombre: ${name}</h3>
    <h3>Apellido: ${lastName}</h3>
    <h3>Teléfono: ${phone}</h3>
    <h3>Correo: ${email}</h3>
    <h3>Razón: ${reason}</h3>
    `

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: "",
            pass: ""
        }
    })

    if(!name || !lastName || !phone || !email || !reason){
        res.status(500).send({message: "Los datos son obligatorios."})
    }
    else{
        res.status(201).send({message: "ok"})
        transporter.sendMail({
            from: '"',
            to: "",
            subject: "",
            html: datos
        })
    }

}

module.exports = {
    putContact
}
```

agradezco su ayuda, ya llevo dos días así y he intentado de todo.

Aclaración : cuando ingreso los datos por postman este si los recibe correctamente y me envía el correo nodemailer como debe ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces el `fetch`, no le estas indicando que los datos que envías son `JSON`, esto se hace mediante headers, especificando el `Content-Type`, así:

```
const params = {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(inputs),
        headers:{
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
        }
}
```

Es posible que sea esto.

Comment: Efectivamente, era eso, en postman estaba el header pero no lo estaba específicando en el parámetro del fetch